# Arrows pure CSS image slider

Tags: html, image, css, slider

So far only the middle slide has correct arrow pointing to the left on the left side and arrow pointing to the right on the right side. But i cannot manage to make when you are on either left or right slide the arrows to be pointing to the right way.

Thank you!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvZGdb

HTML

```
<div id="slides">
 <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" class="set"/>
 <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" class="set"/>
 <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3" class="set"/>

 <div class="mask">
  <div class="overflow">
   <div class="slide"><img src="../images/work.png"/></div>
   <div class="slide"><img src="../images/work.png"/></div>
   <div class="slide"><img src="../images/work.png"/></div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="controls" onclick="">
 <label for="slide1">1</label>
 <label for="slide2">2</label>
 <label for="slide3">3</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input.set { 
display:none; 
}

#slide1:checked ~ .mask .overflow { margin-left:0; }
#slide2:checked ~ .mask .overflow { margin-left:-640px; }
#slide3:checked ~ .mask .overflow { margin-left:-1280px; }

#slides { 
margin:auto; 
width:760px; 
position:relative;
background-color:#096;
}

#slides .mask { 
width:640px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:auto;
}

#slides .overflow { 
width:300%;
-webkit-transition: ease-out 0.5s; 
}

#slides .slide { 
width: 640px;
height:480px; 
float:left; 
background: silver;
}

#controls label { 
display:none; 
width:60px; 
height:60px; 
opacity:0.5; 
position:absolute; 
top:50%; 
margin-top:-30px; 
cursor:pointer; 
background:#0C0;
}

#controls label:hover { 
opacity:1; 
}

#slide1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2), #slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3), #slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2) { right:0; display:block; }
#slide2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1), #slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2) { left:0; display:block; }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking here.  What are "correct navigation arrows"?  Also your codepen is very confusing with broken images, so it isn't providing context.

Comment: I have edited codepen with some images making it more clear. So far only the middle slide has correct arrow pointing to the left on the left side and arrow pointing to the right on the right side. But i cannot manage to make when you are on either left or right slide the arrows to be pointing to the right way.

Comment: You want when you are on the final img arrow to point back ('<')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got you right but I can try. From what I read you want the arrow on the last slide to "shift" backward ("<").

There are few approaches to this solution.

### First way

You add a class when it's on the last div and simply rotate if for 180 deg.

```
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);}
```

### Second way

As in the first way you add a class for this last scenario and you flip it with matrix.

```
#slide3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2) {
  transform: matrix(-1,0,0,1,0,0);}
```

### Third way

For me maybe the best way. You can use :before and content:"" to a letter, icon or symbol to a label. So labels are empty and you "fill" them with before.

### Browser Support

For the first two ways you need to use prefixes.

- **IE > 9** (IE 9 requires prefix)
- **Firefox > 3** ( FF < 15 requires prefix)
- **Chrome** (Chrome < 35 requires prefix)
- **Safari** (requires prefix)
- **Opera** > 10 (Opera < 22 requires prefix)

For more info [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)